# How can I avoid the xmlns namespace attribute passing to child elements in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, apigee

I am a newbie with XSLT. Below is my stylesheet code snippet and I have added the target namespace ="http://tempuri.org/" for the requirement. But it is getting passed as the empty string value attribute (xmlns="") on the child elements coming under ...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <!-- Stylesheet to inject namespaces into a document in specific places -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <soap:Envelope>
            <soap:Header/>
            <soap:Body>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <!-- Handle 'Root' wrapper added by JSON to XML policy -->
                    <xsl:when test="normalize-space(/Root)">
                        <TestProcessMessage xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
                        </TestProcessMessage>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <!-- Handle 'Array' wrapper added by JSON to XML policy -->
                    <xsl:when test="normalize-space(/Array)">
                        <TestProcessMessage>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
                        </TestProcessMessage>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <!-- If the root element is not what was in the schema, add it -->
                    <xsl:when test="not(normalize-space(/TestProcessMessage))">
                        <TestProcessMessage>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
                        </TestProcessMessage>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <!-- everything checks out,  just copy the xml -->
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/Root/*" name="copy-root">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/Array/*" name="copy-array">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(local-name()='Root') and not(local-name()='Array')]" name="copy-all">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template to copy the rest of the nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="comment() | processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

xmlns="" is getting added to the child elements like below.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
               xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
               xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/"
               xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <TestProcessMessage xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <TargetApplication xmlns="">LoyaltyAdaptor</TargetApplication>
         <Chain xmlns="">1000</Chain>
         <Branch xmlns="">0</Branch>
         <InSessionKey xmlns="">0</InSessionKey>
         <MessageNumber xmlns="">0</MessageNumber>
         <Compression xmlns="">0</Compression>
         <TimeOut xmlns="">50000</TimeOut>
         <buffer xmlns="">xxx</buffer>
      </TestProcessMessage>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The requirement is to have the xmlns namespace only on the element "TestProcessMessage" like shown below.

```
<soap:Body>
      <TestProcessMessage xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <TargetApplication xmlns="">LoyaltyAdaptor</TargetApplication>
         <Chain>1000</Chain>
         <Branch>0</Branch>
         <InSessionKey>0</InSessionKey>
         <MessageNumber>0</MessageNumber>
         <Compression>0</Compression>
         <TimeOut>50000</TimeOut>
         <buffer>xxx</buffer>
      </TestProcessMessage>
   </soap:Body>
```

Update:
adding the original WSDL used for this conversion

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<s:element name="Login">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Chain" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Branch" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="LoginResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="LoginResult" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SessionKey" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="ProcessMessage">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TargetApplication" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Chain" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Branch" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="inSessionKey" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="MessageNumber" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Compression" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="buffer" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="TimeOut" type="s:long"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="ProcessMessageResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ProcessMessageResult" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ProcessingTime" type="s:long"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SessionKey" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ResponseBuffer" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="DropCounterCategory">
<s:complexType/>
</s:element>
<s:element name="DropCounterCategoryResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DropCounterCategoryResult" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="TestProcessMessage">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TargetApplication" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Chain" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Branch" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="inSessionKey" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="MessageNumber" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Compression" type="s:int"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="buffer" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="TimeOut" type="s:long"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="TestProcessMessageResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TestProcessMessageResult" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="Watchdog">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Chain" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Branch" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="WatchdogResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WatchdogResult" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ErrorCode" type="s:int"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="Ping">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PingApplication" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ApplicationToPing" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="PingResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PingResult" type="s:boolean"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="Test">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Chain" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Branch" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="TestResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="TestResult" type="s:int"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
</s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="LoginSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Login"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="LoginSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:LoginResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ProcessMessageSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ProcessMessage"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ProcessMessageSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ProcessMessageResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="DropCounterCategorySoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:DropCounterCategory"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="DropCounterCategorySoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:DropCounterCategoryResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="TestProcessMessageSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:TestProcessMessage"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="TestProcessMessageSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:TestProcessMessageResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="WatchdogSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Watchdog"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="WatchdogSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:WatchdogResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="PingSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Ping"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="PingSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:PingResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="TestSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Test"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="TestSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:TestResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="CommpointServiceSoap">
<wsdl:operation name="Login">
<wsdl:input message="tns:LoginSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:LoginSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="ProcessMessage">
<wsdl:input message="tns:ProcessMessageSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:ProcessMessageSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="DropCounterCategory">
<wsdl:input message="tns:DropCounterCategorySoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:DropCounterCategorySoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="TestProcessMessage">
<wsdl:input message="tns:TestProcessMessageSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:TestProcessMessageSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="Watchdog">
<wsdl:input message="tns:WatchdogSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:WatchdogSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="Ping">
<wsdl:input message="tns:PingSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:PingSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="Test">
<wsdl:input message="tns:TestSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:TestSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="CommpointServiceSoap" type="tns:CommpointServiceSoap">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="Login">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Login" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="ProcessMessage">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ProcessMessage" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="DropCounterCategory">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/DropCounterCategory" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="TestProcessMessage">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/TestProcessMessage" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="Watchdog">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Watchdog" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="Ping">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Ping" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="Test">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Test" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="CommpointServiceSoap12" type="tns:CommpointServiceSoap">
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="Login">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Login" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="ProcessMessage">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ProcessMessage" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="DropCounterCategory">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/DropCounterCategory" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="TestProcessMessage">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/TestProcessMessage" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="Watchdog">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Watchdog" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="Ping">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Ping" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="Test">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Test" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="CommpointService">
<wsdl:port name="CommpointServiceSoap" binding="tns:CommpointServiceSoap">
<soap:address location="http://xxx.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="CommpointServiceSoap12" binding="tns:CommpointServiceSoap12">
<soap12:address location="http://yyy.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I have tried various options but nothing solved the problem. Can you please advise how to get this achieved?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to understand is: if you create elements in the right namespace, the namespace declarations will look after themselves. The `xmlns=""` declaration is there because you created the element in the wrong namespace. Specifically, you created a no-namespace element when you wanted an element in namespace `http://tempuri.org/`.

When you create an element, it doesn't automatically go in the same namespace as its parent element. It goes in whatever namespace you put it in. If that's different from the namespace of its parent element, a namespace declaration will be output to reflect this difference.

Now, you haven't actually shown us the code that creates the `Chain` element (for example), but that's the code that's wrong. There are three ways of creating elements (literal result elements, the `xsl:element` instruction, and `xsl:copy`) and the way to fix the problem is going to depend on which of these you are using.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I have updated the WSDL here. The requirement was to convert the WSDL SOAP into JSON format and this issue came up when during the conversion. There is a SOAPAction on the WSDL which will be adding the namespace to the operation but I am not sure how to fit that in the XSLT. I need to get the xmlns only on the root of every operation mentioned in the WSDL but it is coming even to child elements. <soap:Body>
      <TestProcessMessage xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         ...
   </soap:Body>